# Compiling C file is fine, but exe file displays nothing

Tags: c

I've been trying to figure out what's going on, but it's driving me nuts. I have this script here, it compiles fine (I'm using GCC), but when I try to run the compiled exe, the terminal just pauses for a brief moment and exits. I have no clue what's going on, any help would be appreciated.

```
// not sure what's on
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "extra.h"
int RanNum(int StartNum, int StopNum);
int main() {
    printf("Hey\n");
    int magicNum, guess, choice;
    do {
        printf("Guess the right number: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        guess = 1;
        magicNum = RanNum(3,10);
        if (choice == magicNum){
            printf("You win! \n");
            break;
        } else {
            int rem = (3 - guess);
            printf("\nYou have %d tries remaining \n", rem);
        }
        guess++;
    } while (guess <= 3);
    if (guess > 3) {        
        printf("You lost... We can try again...\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int RanNum(int StartNum, int StopNum){  
    int *list;
    int Divided;
    int range = StartNum - StopNum;
    int RandArray[range];
    for (int i=StartNum; i<StopNum; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<range+1; j++) {
            RandArray[j] = i;
        }
    }
    list = RandArray;
    Divided = (StartNum+StopNum)/range;
    return list[Divided];   
}
```

Comment: What's in "extra.h"?

Comment: extra.h just has the RanNum function that I pasted into this file.

Comment: `RandArray[j]` goes out of bounds. Using asan (https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) is a good way to find this sort of problem.

Comment: Also, it's useful to run gcc with the -Wall and -Wextra flags - those can be quite helpful. :)

Comment: `RanNum` is weird (apart from the buffer overflow). What's the `j` loop for? Why isn't it just `RandNum[i - StartNum] = i;` ? Also what's the need for any array? `return (StartNum+StopNum)/range - StartNum;` seems to do the same as the entire function. From the name it sounds like it should return a random number, but there's no randomness in it at all.

Comment: @PaulHankin Thank you! I'll check it out right away. As for the j loop, I'll take a second look at that, now that I think of it.

Comment: @RadheS., welcome to stackoverflow. When asking a question here it's best to make your code as small as possible while still reproducing the error. This is how you can debug in general, and so you'll often pick up the error yourself this way, but otherwise it makes it easy for us to read and understand. You'll get more responses that way.  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `RanNum` runs into UB ([undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)) and a silent exit is one possible manifestation of UB.

  ```
  int RanNum(int StartNum, int StopNum){  // <---- called with StartNum = 3, StopNum = 10
      int *list;
      int Divided;
      int range = StartNum - StopNum;     // <---- range = 3 - 10 = -7
      int RandArray[range];               // <---- array of negative size       *** UB
      for (int i=StartNum; i<StopNum; i++) {
          for (int j=0; j<range+1; j++) { // <---- after 'range' is fixed to be > 0
              RandArray[j] = i;           // <---- the last iteration j = range
          }                               // <---- overruns the array bound     *** UB
      }
  // ...
  }
  ```
- Once the first problems are fixed, there is another one with the `main` loop.

  ```
  int magicNum, guess, choice;  // <---- 'guess' is defined but not initialized
  do {
      printf("Guess the right number: ");
      scanf("%d", &choice);
      guess = 1;                // <---- 'guess' is initialized to '1` in each iteration

      /* code that does not change or use 'guess' */

      guess++;                  // <---- 'guess' was '1' and is now incremented to '2'
  } while (guess <= 3);         // <---- always true, so loop continues until number guessed
  ```